# How do I get vertical centering in a core-toolbar polymer component

Tags: polymer

http://jsbin.com/fekiyi/1/edit

I want to vertically center my elements inside this core-toolbar, according to docs, i could do it with "middle" class or with a horizontal centered layout. but it wont work either way.

Thanks in advance.

```
<core-toolbar id="topo-do-titulo" class="medium-tall">

  <paper-icon-button id="navicon" icon="menu" class="middle"></paper-icon-button>

  <div id="titulo" class="indent middle" flex>Whatever Title</div>

  <paper-icon-button class="indent middle" id="viva-close-button" fill="false" icon="close">
    <a href="#" id="button_close"></a>
  </paper-icon-button>

  <paper-shadow z="1"></paper-shadow>
</core-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're correct, this doesn't work in a medium-tall toolbar.  I'm not sure whether it's supposed to or not. It does work as expected with a "tall" toolbar.

Example: http://jsbin.com/fitahe/27/edit?html,output

I've filed [a bug](https://github.com/Polymer/core-toolbar/issues/14) for clarification. I think it's probably intentional, and we just need to improve the documentation.

The toolbar is designed to harmonize with the material design spec, which basically states that toolbars can be single, double, or triple height (where "medium-tall" is double-height and "tall" is triple height). It specifies that controls should be pinned to the top or bottom of taller toolbars, which you can do using the "top" and "bottom" classes.

In the case of the triple-height core-toolbar, it also provides support for a "middle" class. It's not clear whether this fits with the material design guidelines, but it seems reasonable enough.

Unfortunately, it does mean that you can't easily center your content vertically on a medium-tall toolbar, because that's not the way the control is designed. Anything pinned in the middle would overlap with any top and bottom controls.

If after reading all that you still want to center your content on a medium-tall toolbar, here's some CSS to override the middlebar styling:

`core-toolbar.medium-tall::shadow #middleBar {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
    transform: translateY(50%);
  }`

Example: http://jsbin.com/fitahe/32/edit?html,output

Comment: Thank you, it works, although thinking about what you said i may change it to tall or align it to top giving me title room even tabs room or some material design stuff it may be useful in near feature of my development...i don't know.